# MQTT broker + mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mqtt

How do i integrate MQTT broker with mongoDB ?

I publish gps co ordinates from a client to the broker and would like to store that in MQTT broker with mongoDB,

Would appreciate if some pointers are shared for the same

Answer (score 5):

If you want your broker to directly store the message reliably to the database, you could use [HiveMQ](http://www.hivemq.com) and write a MongoDB plugin. The concept is described in [this blog post](http://www.hivemq.com/mqtt-sql-database/).

Another idea would be to use a wildcard subscriber which gets all messages and stores that to MongoDB. That wouldn't be a direct integration but would work if you don't want to scale out.

Answer (score 5):

I searched around and didn't find any suitable solution for myself so I created one: https://github.com/izmailoff/mqtt-mongo.

See the [README](https://github.com/izmailoff/mqtt-mongo/blob/master/README.md) for all details. Essentially it's a standalone service that connects to MQTT broker and MongoDB and subscribes to the topics you are interested in. You can select a collection for each topic in the config.

The design goals are to have resilient, lightweight and fast service which you can also customize with code in Java/Scala or any JVM language that supports such integration.

Comment: Just an update I've refreshed the repo so it can be built easily and published docker on dockerhub: https://hub.docker.com/r/izmailoff/mqtt-mongo

Answer (score 4):

Probably the simplest way would be to use Node-Red (http://nodered.org)

If the MQTT payload is a json object already in the correct format then one MQTT input node linked to a mongodb node will do this.

If you need to change the payload before inserting it you can include a function node to remap it.

Answer (score -2):

It is an old question but I needed to do something similar.  I have a subscriber that subscribes to the topics that I am interested in saving to mongo.  It simply saves the messages in the db.  I have not yet looked at scaling issue yet.  But in my situation, I can partition these messages based on topics.